# Inputs to eager execution function cannot be Keras symbolic tensors, Custom loss function, Tensorflow 2, Gradient Tape

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow2.0, gradienttape

I am trying to use a custom loss function in my `Keras` model (TensorFlow 2). This custom loss (ideally) will calculate the data loss plus the residual of a physical equation (say, diffusion equation, Navier Stokes, etc.). This residual error is based on the model output derivative wrt its inputs and I want to use `GradientTape`.

In this MWE, I removed the data loss term and other equation losses, and just used the derivative of the output wrt its first input. The dataset can be found [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jbrownlee/Datasets/master/pima-indians-diabetes.data.csv).

```
from numpy import loadtxt
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
import tensorflow as tf #tf.__version__ = '2.3.0'
# tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()
# load the dataset
dataset = loadtxt('pima-indians-diabetes.csv', delimiter=',')
# split into input (X) and output (y) variables
X = dataset[:,0:8] #X.shape = (768, 8)
y = dataset[:,8]

def customLoss(yTrue,yPred):
    x_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(model.input, dtype=tf.float32)
    x_tensor = tf.cast(x_tensor, tf.float32)
    with tf.GradientTape() as t:
        t.watch(x_tensor)
        output = model(x_tensor)
    DyDX = t.gradient(output, x_tensor)    
    dy_t = DyDX[:, 5:6][0]
    R_pred=dy_t
    # loss_data = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(yTrue - yPred), axis=-1)
    loss_PDE = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(R_pred))
    return loss_PDE

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(12, input_dim=8, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(12, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(12, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss=customLoss, optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X, y, epochs=15, batch_size=10)
```

After execution, I get this `_SymbolicException`:

```
_SymbolicException: Inputs to eager execution function cannot be Keras symbolic tensors, but found [<tf.Tensor 'dense_6_input:0' shape=(None, 8) dtype=float32>]
```

When I uncomment `tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()`, the issue seems to vanish and the model starts training. I was wondering why I am getting this `_SymbolicException` and how can I work it out without disabling eager execution. Any ideas?